# Compilation fails after install library into a path not included in compilation

Tags: c++, openssl

#### Scenario:

On a Debian 8, I have installed openssl library (both runtime & dev), version 1.0.1t. Those were installed using `apt-get`. So, default location: `/usr/include/` and `/usr/lib`.

I compile a file that uses openssl library: (generated from `qmake`)

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -DHAVE_OPENSSL -D_REENTRANT -DENABLE_IPV6 -DTIXML_USE_STL -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATED -DQT_NO_DEBUG -I. -I. -Isrc -Isrc/engine -Isrc/gui -Isrc/gui/qt -Isrc/gui/qt/qttools -Isrc/net -Isrc/engine/local_engine -Isrc/engine/network_engine -Isrc/config -Isrc/core -Isrc/third_party/websocketpp -isystem /usr/include -isystem /usr/include/mysql -isystem /usr/include/mysql++ -I/opt/gsasl/include -I~/Qt/5.9.0_static/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o obj/crypthelper.o src/core/common/crypthelper.cpp
```

It works perfect. Please, note that there is no `/usr/local/` headers included.

#### Target:

Do the same using openssl 1.1.1b (to reproduce a bug)

I install openssl 1.1.1b from source (without removing 1.0.1t), which installs into `/usr/local`.
First, to make sure nothing has changed, I run same command (which has no reference to `/usr/local`), and it complains:

```
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:66:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:73,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:156,
                 from src/core/openssl_wrapper.h:75,
                 from src/core/common/crypthelper.cpp:34:
/usr/local/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:20:3: error: #error OPENSSL_ALGORITHM_DEFINES no longer supported    <---- WHY???
 # error OPENSSL_ALGORITHM_DEFINES no longer supported
```

Why does it complain from a file located in `/usr/local`? Why does it include?
There is no reference to this directory! I don't understand.

PD: Sorry for title, nothing better came to me. Feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/include` is in default search paths for your compiler

You can check those by calling `echo | g++ -E -v -`

You should get output similar to this:

```
...
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
...
```

By passing `-isystem /usr/include` you move `/usr/include` to the top of the search list and headers from openssl 1.0.1 are found first. But `<openssl/opensslconf.h>` is located elsewhere (for me it's `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h`) which is searched after `/usr/local/include`, so the version from openssl 1.1.1 is found first.

You can fix that by locating the directory containing correct opensslconf.h and modifying your build to pass it with `-isystem` flag

Comment: You are right. All headers from ssl are in `/usr/include/openssl`, except `opensslconf.h` that was in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl`. 
It's like developers are making fun of me. I could solve it just adding `-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` 
Thanks a lot.